# How to convert datagridview checkbox column to textbox column?

Tags: vb.net

I have two datagridview in a form. What I trying to do is

my datagridview1 has some rows and when i add same id row in datagridview2 then is should automatically convert datagridview1 checkbox to textbox when condition is matched because checkbox cannot disable in datagridview. how to do this?

```vb
Dim subCodeList As New List(Of String)

For i As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
    subCodeList.Add(DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value.ToString())
Next      
  
For i As Integer = 0 To DataGridView2.Rows.Count - 1
    If subCodeList.Contains(DataGridView2.Rows(i).Cells(16).Value.ToString()) Then
        DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value = Nothing
        DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(0) = New DataGridViewTextBoxCell()
        DataGridView1.Rows(i).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Drawing.Color.Yellow
    End If
Next
```

Comment: NEVER tell us THAT an error occurred without providing ALL the relevant details, i.e. WHERE it occurred and WHAT type it was and the error message. This information is provided to you by the debugger for a reason.

Comment: Also, why have two loops over the same list? Why not put the contents of the second loop into the first, after its current contents? It's possible that you might want the first action done for all rows before starting the second action but I see no evidence of that here.